# Maven surefire unittests pom configuration

Tags: unit-testing, maven, pom.xml, surefire

I need to write 2 unit tests. The first one (say `envVarTrueTest()`) requires an environment variable (say `INFO`) to be set. I set this environment variable in `surefire` plugin properties in `pom.xml` as

```
<configuration>
    <environmentVariables>
        <INFO>infovalue</INFO>
    </environmentVariables>
</configuration>
```

For the second unit test, the environment variable `INFO` should NOT have been set. I don't know how to *unset* the variable for the second test now.

Is there a way to do this, either by configuring `pom.xml` or through the java code in the unit tests?

Comment: A clunky thought that comes to mind is you could run the test separately with a different profile.  I hope there's a better way though.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to deal with this is to write your test differently and make maven's pom unrelated to the test's result.  [Here's how you get environment variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html), you're probably already doing that.  Now make your system under test accept a `java.util.Map` that you get from [getenv](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28%29).  In your tests, fake these values.  In one test the value is set, in the other test it's not.  But it gets set *in* the test, not in maven.

Comment: Agreed. A problem with testing environment variables directly is you inevitably want unit tests that test how the code behaves with different settings.

Comment: Can't cut maven out. Have to use it.